# Randomly feature mapping

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I'm taking machine learning course  In the second part of exercise 2, we are supposed to use feature map. And they added new features by mapping the features into all polynomial terms of x1 and x2 up to the sixth power. However, my instructor told me I shouldn't use this algorithm and instead I should randomly add features. However, we add new features in order to better classify.So wouldn't adding features randomly make this more complicated? So can we add features randomly or should we follow some rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding new features (e.g. polynomial of the existing features) helps to reduce the error by using complex hypothesis. But this may lead to overfitting the training data and may not produce efficient results on the test set.

**So, in order to add new features, following should be considered:**

1) Manually select which feature to keep by analyzing the results.

2) Other way is use all features and then use regularization which will automatically give less importance to less contributing features and more importance to more contributing features towards target variable.

3) Randomly selecting features may or may not help always. It is always required to choose those features which contribute more towards target variable. Random selection may not be the appropriate solution.

**Important Note**

Always use validation set to check the error during training.
While working with polynomial features, always check the learning curve to see model should not overfitting the train data. If such happens, try to increase the regularization parameter (lambda). Regularization helps in reducing over fitting.